# How is traffic routed on a Mac when you are connected to multiple networks?

Tags: networking, router

I have a Mac (MacOS 10.15.1) connected to two routers, one via wifi and one via ethernet.

**I am wondering what happens when I make a tcp request to an arbitrary ip address, does the request only get sent out one network adapter to one router, and if so what decides that.**

This question is motivated by the fact that when I'm connected to both routers, I only seem to be able to access devices on one of them (pings to ip addresses on the second network timeout).

Here's what they look like in network settings, each has a different IP
[image]
[image]

When I ping the routers from the mac I see this:

```
➜  ~ ping 10.1.10.1
PING 10.1.10.1 (10.1.10.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.1.10.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=5.055 ms

➜  ~ ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
```

I can see via `route` that the 192.* requests are getting sent to the 10.* gateway

```
local ➜  ~ route get 192.168.0.1
   route to: 192.168.0.1
destination: default
       mask: default
    gateway: 10.1.10.1
  interface: en0
```

Answer (score 1):

The wifi is probably set to be prioritized first. Since you have an active Wifi connection, the physical Ethernet connection is not "active".

You can check which order your interfaces are in by going to System Preferences -> Network. Currently, my wifi has first priority, then Bluetooth, then the thunderbolt port which would be utilized if I had an Ethernet adapter.

If you go into the network settings and reprioritize the interfaces by clicking the cog icon and selecting `Set Service Order...`

Keeping each interfaces `Configure IPv4` setting on `Using DHCP` might allow you to use both actively.

If that doesn't work, try setting the physical Ethernet setting to manual, assign an IP address and subnet mask, then try leaving the router section blank.

I'd like to test this out for you, but I unfortunately don't have an adapter.